# Me aparece un error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, excepciones

Me aparece el siguiente error en consola:

```
Puede entrar un coche
Coche devuelto
Puede entrar un coche
Coche devuelto
Puede entrar un coche
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at Garaje.aceptarCoche(Garaje.java:27)
>         at Actividad2.main(Actividad2.java:21)

en las siguientes clases:

Motor

```
public class Motor {

//Atributos
private int Litrosdeaceite;
private int CV;

//Constructor
public Motor(int CV) {
    this.Litrosdeaceite = 0;
    this.CV = CV;
}

//Getter
public int getLitrosdeaceite() {
    return Litrosdeaceite;
}

public int getCV() {
    return CV;
}

//Setter
public void setLitrosdeaceite(int litrosdeaceite) {
    Litrosdeaceite = litrosdeaceite;
}

}
```

Coche

```
public class Coche {

//Atributos
private Motor motor;
public String Marca;
public String Modelo;
public double Averias;

//Constructor
public Coche(String marca, String modelo) {
    this.Marca = marca;
    this.Modelo = modelo;
}

//Getter
public Motor getMotor() {
    return motor;
}

public String getMarca() {
    return Marca;
}

public String getModelo() {
    return Modelo;
}

public double getAverias() {
    return Averias;
}

//Método acumular avería
public void acumularAveria(double valorAveria) {
    this.Averias += valorAveria;
}

}
```

Garaje

```
public class Garaje {

//Atributos
public Coche coche;
public String AveriaAsociada;
public int NumeroCoches;

//Método1
public void aceptarCoche(Coche coche, String AveriaAsociada) {
    this.coche = coche;
    this.AveriaAsociada = AveriaAsociada;

//Atender un coche a cada momento
if (NumeroCoches == 0) {
    System.out.println("Puede entrar un coche");
} else {
    System.out.println("Garaje ocupado");
}

//Acumular averias
this.coche.acumularAveria(Math.random()*100);
this.NumeroCoches = 1;

//Aumentar en 10 el aceite del motor
if (AveriaAsociada.equals("Aceite")) {
    int Litrosdeaceite = coche.getMotor().getLitrosdeaceite();
    coche.getMotor().setLitrosdeaceite(Litrosdeaceite + 10);
}
}

//Método2
public void devolverCoche() {
    this.NumeroCoches = 0;
    System.out.println("Coche devuelto");
}

 }
```

y en esta:

```
public class Actividad2 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Garaje garaje = new Garaje();

    Coche coche1 = new Coche("Marca", "Modelo");
    Coche coche2 = new Coche("Marca", "Modelo");

    garaje.aceptarCoche(coche1, "Averia1");
    garaje.devolverCoche();

    garaje.aceptarCoche(coche2, "Averia2");
    garaje.devolverCoche();

    garaje.aceptarCoche(coche1, "Aceite");
    garaje.devolverCoche();

    garaje.aceptarCoche(coche2, "Aceite");
    garaje.devolverCoche();

    System.out.println("Informacion coche: " + coche1.getMarca() + coche1.getModelo() + coche1.getAverias());
    System.out.println("Informacion coche: " + coche2.getMarca() + coche2.getModelo() + coche2.getAverias());




}

}
```

¿Qué debo cambiar o tengo mal?

Comment: Deberías poner también el código de Coche para ver si el fallo no te lo da el método getAverias(). Para mí es el principal sospechoso.

Comment: De acuerdo, ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: Acabo de usar tu código y me sale todo correcto excepto porque quite la parte del Motor. Pega también eso.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Yo creo que sería más conveniente que pusiera todas las clases que se usan en el ejercicio, ya que por ejemplo la pregunta sin la clase Garaje no tiene sentido.

Comment: Ya están todas puestas.

Comment: Un consejo, a la hora de darle nombre a las variables, trata de que sean siempre en minúsculas salvo que sean constantes, te será muy útil este enlace http://www.um.es/docencia/vjimenez/ficheros/practicas/ConvencionesCodigoJava.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El atributo `Motor` de tu clase `coche` nunca le asignas un valor, por eso al hacer `coche.getMotor()` retorna `Null` , la forma más sencilla de solucionar el error es asignando un valor a dicho atributo, mediante el constructor **(Quizá no la mejor pero funciona)**

```
public Coche(String marca, String modelo,int  cv) {
  this.Marca = marca;
  this.Modelo = modelo;
  /* LLamamos al constructor de Motor y le pasamos el parametro cv*/
  this.motor= new Motor(cv);
}
```

y en tu `Actividad2`

```
Coche coche1 = new Coche("Marca", "Modelo",12);
Coche coche2 = new Coche("Marca", "Modelo",14);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que nunca instancias el objeto Motor. Ponlo en el constructor de Coche por ejemplo:

```
public Coche(String marca, String modelo, int CV) {
  this.Marca = marca;
  this.Modelo = modelo;
  this.motor = new Motor(CV);
}
```

Y lo llamas en Actividad:

```
Coche coche1 = new Coche("Marca", "Modelo", 90);
```